# Should you wash beef before freezing?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, beef

I have bought a 3 kg vacuum-sealed package of ribeye steaks. The steaks are very fresh and are essentially floating in blood.

I would like to repackage the steaks one by one, so that I can thaw them separately. Should I wash them before freezing, or is it ok to directly package them in plastic wrap as they are?

Comment: When I do this, if they are a little bloody I wrap the steaks in a little paper towel. Once mostly dry I set them on a baking sheet and stick them directly in the freezer overnight. Once rock hard I wrap them in plastic wrap and they are good to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does meat need to be washed before preparation?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/does-meat-need-to-be-washed-before-preparation)

Comment: While the duplicate I've linked to is about washing before preparation, rather than before freezing, I think it still applies — rinsing the meat off can splash potentially contaminated liquid around the kitchen, and that applies whether your meat is about to be cooked or frozen to be cooked later. Do you think it answers your question?

Comment: wash no, but rinse and dry before freezing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a note, a pet peeve of mine and something that may help you feel better, that red liquid is not blood. It is Myoglobin, a protein that found only in muscle. Blood tends to spoil very rapidly and meat which was not properly drained of blood will typically spoil or at least taste unlike what you want. Myoglobin however as it ages is what helps give aged meat its distinct, and for many, better flavor. When meat is seared, it also contributes to the caramelized crust, another level of flavor many like. 
 Myoglobin is related to Hemoglobin, red blood cells, and works with it to deliver oxygen to the muscle, but it is not the same and does not age the same.

As to what to do when repacking, well, as comments have given multiple answers, I would also say that is personal choice.  For me, best taste is to still have some, but a lot of the liquid is just messy, so I would tend to pat some off but not rinse or wash.  Rinse if you prefer, but I certainly would not soak or scrub.  When you thaw, almost certainly more will be released from the steak, so in the end the results will likely be about the same between patting and leaving it.  I would just think you will want to minimize introducing ice crystals which may reduce the quality of the frozen and thawed meat.